# Wrap words in overflown hidden element div in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, overflow

I have a div and inside that div is some text. What I want to do is if the text is more than 2 lines, it will put some dots after the last word. Something like this.

```
 __________________________________
|asdadasdasdadadaasdasdasdasdasdasd|
|asdadasdasdadadaasdasdasdasdasd...|
 __________________________________
```

```html
<div class='project-name ' ng-if='true' >{{task.comment}}</div>
```

When clicking on the div the div will expand to see the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of text. if its a pre tag, has new lines or the wrapper-width is tight or if it's a responsive site (in that case it has to be dynamic and properly best solved with css somehow).
You should do what is best for you. perhaps a own custom filter would be best

But maybe just the simplest would be

```
{{task.comment | limitTo:240}}
```

If the good CSS gods will implement http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#max-lines we can do this in pure CSS using fragments (new) and max-lines (new)